# Does anybody have experience with Dump(8) and the ext4 fs

Tags: ext4, dump

I have done some research online and some people claim dump/restore have good ext4 support and others claim the system is broken and restores come back corrupt. My question is, do they work well together, in your experience?

Comment: somebody must have an answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `dump` works just fine with ext4.  Of course, make sure you are using the latest version of it.  You also could easily test this yourself.